# MQTT sending messages over multiple ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, mqtt

i have a problem with my mqttconfiguration. Connection works fine. 
Every time I send a message, switch to another ViewController, come back and push again the sending button, no message received at my raspberry.
So the problem is, when I switch over multiple ViewController I can't send messages anymore. 
I don't find my mistake in my code:

Swiftfile for MQTT-Config:

```
class ConnectionFunctions{
struct staticMQTT {
    static var mqttClient: CocoaMQTT!
}
func configureMQTT() {
    let clientID = "Tablet"
    let host = "192.168.2.106"
    let port = UInt16(1883)
    staticMQTT.mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: host, port: port)
    staticMQTT.mqttClient.username = ""
    staticMQTT.mqttClient.password = ""
    staticMQTT.mqttClient.keepAlive = 60
    staticMQTT.mqttClient.delegate = self
}
func sendMessage(topic:String, message:String){
    staticMQTT.mqttClient.publish(topic, withString: message)
}
```

First View Controller:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

//MQTT Setup
var mqttfuncs=ConnectionFunctions()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mqttfuncs.configureMQTT()
}
    @IBAction func ConnectingButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ConnectionFunctions.staticMQTT.mqttClient.connect()
}
@IBAction func Test(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttfuncs.sendMessage(topic: "Test", message: "main")
    mqttfuncs.receiveMessage(topic: "Test2")
}
```

Second ViewController

```
class ComponentDataController: UIViewController {
let mqttfuncs = ConnectionFunctions()
    @IBAction func TestSending(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttfuncs.sendMessage(topic: "Test", message: "component")
}
```

Sending with First View Controller works fine, after this sending with second ViewController also works fine, but when I switch back to my First View Controller and push the Sending Button nothing happens.

Hope you can help me!
Best Regards
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have tried to set up your MQTT client class as a singleton, but then code looks a little *off*.

Use

```
class MQTTManager {
    static let shared = MQTTManager()

    private var mqttClient: CocoaMQTT

    private init() {
        let clientID = "Tablet"
        let host = "192.168.2.106"
        let port = UInt16(1883)
        self.mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: host, port: port)
        self.mqttClient.username = ""
        self.mqttClient.password = ""
        self.mqttClient.keepAlive = 60
        self.mqttClient.delegate = self
        self.mqttClient.connect()
    }

    func sendMessage(topic:String, message:String){
        self.mqttClient.publish(topic, withString: message)
    }

    //... other functions which you haven't shown
}
```

Then to send a message you can simply say

```
MQTTManager.shared.sendMessage(topic:"topic", message:"message")
```

Comment: Hi Paul this looks good but I think there is a little mistake? If I try your solution it says "Instance member 'shared' cannot be used on type of 'MQTTManager'. "

Comment: Sorry. There was a missing `static`

Comment: Thats exactly what I want! Thank you so much